# Java EE. EJB vs CDI bean

Tags: java-ee, ejb

В чем разница между EJB и CDI bean? Когда какой бин нужно использовать?
Я пока использовал только EJB, но обертывание исключений в EJBExeption превращает жизнь в кошмар.

Comment: Методы EJB, если не задано иначе, автоматически выполняются в транзакции. В CDI нужно самостоятельно подключаться к транзакции. К EJB можно подключаться с удалённых клиентов, если он имеет remote-интерфейс. CDI только для локального применения.

Comment: Вот ещё можно отметить, что имеют различное управление lifecycl-ом

Comment: Я так понял, в большинстве случаях лучше использовать CDI?

Comment: Раз на раз не приходится. У них ведь разное предназначение. Где-то EJB лучше, где-то CDI. Можно их использовать совместно. Инъектить друг в дружку. Наверно предполагается, что EJB - для проведения транзакций, сервисов каких-то внешних. Для всего остального CDI.